# Cannot find the signature?

Tags: smartcard

Use a smart card is digitally signed, there is an error, tip:

Cannot find the signature?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RLHj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open certificate manager, remove and plug the smart card reader or smart card again. Right click "Personal", and click "Refresh". After reloading the certificate, retry signature function.